# How to uninstall something from /usr/local/bin if it is installed in /opt/homebrew/bin

Tags: terminal, applications, homebrew, monterey

what the title says
for example,

```
> where dockutil
/opt/homebrew/bin/dockutil
/opt/homebrew/bin/dockutil
/usr/local/bin/dockutil
```

how would you remove the redundant installation(s)

Comment: What is the output of running `brew info dockutil` command?

Comment: How did you INSTALL the copy in /usr/local/bin ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the file you want to delete in `/usr/local/bin/` is the actual file:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
sudo rm dockutil
```

Edit - This will work on symbolic links as well.

Comment: This works even if it is a symbolic link.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct, @nohillside.